# Problem when plotting my data with Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am implementing a Highcharts graphic, specifically this https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic, but I need to show a quantity with a date, at the time of executing it, this appears:

[image]

**I just need to show the line as in the example**

How can I solve this? I think that there should be some option to avoid being drawn that way

My code:

```
$.getJSON('assistants_status_by_event', function (data) {
        $('#assistants_status_by_event').highcharts({
            title: {
                text: ''
            },

            subtitle: {
                text: ''
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Numero de asistentes'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle'
            },

            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    label: {
                        connectorAllowed: false
                    }
                }
            },

            series: [{
                type: 'area',
                name: 'Confirmados',
                data: data['confirmed'][0]['data']
            }, {
                type: 'area',
                name: 'Pendientes',
                data: data['pending'][0]['data']
            }],

            responsive: {
                rules: [{
                    condition: {
                        maxWidth: 500
                    },
                    chartOptions: {
                        legend: {
                            layout: 'horizontal',
                            align: 'center',
                            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        });
    });
```

My data:

[image]

Comment: Do you need x-axis to be of type date ? 
If yes please try using highstock https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line

Comment: You've set `series.type = 'area'` remove it and you will have the basic line chart. Is it all what you need?